# Ubuntu 22.04 ethernet icon appeared and the internet is is not working websites giving dns error

Tags: networking, internet, dns, ethernet, resolvconf

So I was using a vpn on Ubuntu 22.04 and when I switched country it gor stuck and crashed after I which rebooted my system but when I checked the location and time it was still showing the VPN location. After which the Ethernet icon appeared on the title bar (top right corner) and the internet stopped working.
The websites are giving error that the DNS address could not be found.
I changed the resolv.conf file and  tried nameserver 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 but no fruition.
I am desperate for help also I am new to Linux I really need this to complete my project as soon as possible

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As @waltinator notes, your question as written is unclear and difficult to understand. First, you mention "it got stuck and crashed." What got stuck and crashed? What does "got stuck" mean? Also, were you using a VPN application, or a VPN entry in Network Manager (settings) that you configured yourself? If the former, then you could confirm if the VPN app is still running by running the System Monitor app and checking processes (or running `top` on the command line).